# How to get Reports properly by using JBehave?

Tags: java, jbehave, scenarios, jira-plugin

I am using JBehave to run Scenarios, i have taken an example from **[WebSite](http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2011/03/automated-acceptance-testing-using-jbehave/)** , it is executing properly and generating reports in trarget/jbehave folder.
but the result is showing every time as zero.
(i have taken same example he given in the website)

i need to configure any other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the end, I found that I am missing one of the format type STATS in the code
We can use different Format's like HTML, XML, CONSOLE, IDE_CONSOLE etc..
STATS must be needed to get the Statistics for the Reports.

```
StoryReporterBuilder().withFormats( Format.CONSOLE, Format.STATS, Format.HTML )
```

that will generate Statistics for the Reports.